# Contact Form 7 emails went to spam folder

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, spam, contact-form

I'm using Wordpress plugin named: 'Contact form 7' to send emails to admin when a user fills a form. But all emails sent to spam folder. I tried using `WP-Mail-SMTP` to send emails using smtp. but same result.
When I try to send a email through webmail of my hosting panel, Email is sent to inbox, so the server IP is not blacklisted.
[image: WP Smtp email]

What should I do? Do you know another solution?

Answer (score 0):

The default CF 7 'from' field needs to be a valid email address, if you leave this empty then mostly it will result in going to the junk/spam folder. Change it to a proper email address, even noreply@yourdomain.com will work better than the default

Comment: It's currently a valid email address: info@myvc.ir. So what do you think now?

Comment: try and set the headers for your mail, add a cc and change the footer of the mail, this should work. if it doesn't the chance is that your host is marked as spam sender. you may consider an other contact form plugin like gravity forms, this is a paid plugin but it is in my opinion the best contact form plugin around

Comment: When I told that I can send emails through my hosting webmail panel into inbox, It doesn't mean my host is not marked as spam sender?